# how to print return variable from api(javascript) inside php tag?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

How do I print the success variable r in script tag. The r variable contains the value from api. But I am getting php errors.

```
if (Login::isLoggedIn()) {

    echo "
            $('.btn1').click(function(){
              $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'api/follow?id={$userid}&artid={$id}',
                processData: false,
                contentType: 'json/application',
                data: '',
                success: function(r){
                  console.log(r)
                  ('#followdiv').html("'+r.follow+'")//error
                },
                error: function(r){

                }
              });
           });
           ";
}
```

how do I print r.follow?

I tried in different ways but its not working. Plz help me.

Comment: What's the error that you get?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''+r.follow+'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\future\artistprofile.php on line 488

Comment: The " you have added before r.follow must have ended the string that was being echoed. You need to escape it using \

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to concatenate `r.follow` with anything, so get rid of `"'+r.follow+'"`.

Your `contentType: 'json/application'` is wrong in two ways: first, the correct name is `application/json`; second, you're sending empty data, that's not valid JSON. You're sending all the parameters in the URL, it's not clear why you're using `POST` at all.

If you meant to specify that the response is JSON, that's done using the `dataType:` option, not `contentType:`.

```
echo "
        $('.btn1').click(function(){
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'api/follow?id={$userid}&artid={$id}',
            processData: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: '',
            success: function(r){
              console.log(r)
              $('#followdiv').html(r.follow)
            },
            error: function(r){

            }
          });
       });
       ";
```